# Firebase Push Notification - XCode 8.0 / Swift 3.0/ ios 10.0

Tags: firebase, swift3, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase for Push Notifications.

In `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, I have following line :

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

I get the following error message :

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Firebase SDK to **4.0.0** and add the following code :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        // .sandbox is used during development, later on it can be changed to .prod

        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox) 
 }
```